# How to send a list of data to postgresql from python and then iterate trough that list into an insert postgresql function?

Tags: python, sql, database, postgresql, insert

I already have a python code that send the data to the postgresql function  that i also created, but now i want to send a list to that function, but I'm not sure how to actually create that kind of postgresql function.

Postgresql Function that will insert one row looks like this. But i want to send a list of data from python and then loop trough that list inside of this function.

```
        CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION asg.insert_asg(
        recommendation_account text,
        recommendation_region text,
        recommendation_time text,
        asg_name text,
        asset_id text,
        launch_configuration_name text,
        min_size integer,
        max_size integer,
        desired_capacity integer,
        default_cooldown integer,
        availability_zones text,
        load_balancers_classic text,
        load_balancers_classic_missing text[],
        load_balancers_target_groups text,
        load_balancers_target_groups_missing text[],
        instances text[],
        create_time text,
        tags text[],
        termination_policies text,
        new_instances_protected_from_scale_in boolean,
        cloud_fit boolean,
        recommendations_content text[])
        RETURNS integer
        LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
        COST 100
        VOLATILE PARALLEL UNSAFE
    AS $BODY$
    DECLARE 
            new_asg_id integer;
            
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO asg.asg(recommendation_account, recommendation_region, recommendation_time, asg_name, asset_id, launch_configuration_name, min_size, max_size, desired_capacity, default_cooldown, availability_zones, load_balancers_classic, load_balancers_target_groups, create_time, termination_policies, new_instances_protected_from_scale_in, cloud_fit, load_balancers_classic_missing, load_balancers_target_groups_missing, instances, tags)
            VALUES(recommendation_account, recommendation_region, recommendation_time, asg_name, asset_id, launch_configuration_name, min_size, max_size, desired_capacity, default_cooldown, availability_zones, load_balancers_classic, load_balancers_target_groups, create_time, termination_policies, new_instances_protected_from_scale_in, cloud_fit, load_balancers_classic_missing, load_balancers_target_groups_missing, instances, tags)
            RETURNING asg.asg_id
            INTO new_asg_id;
        
        INSERT INTO asg.recommendations(recommendations_content, asg_id)
            VALUES (recommendations_content, new_asg_id);
        
        RETURN new_asg_id;
    END;
    $BODY$;

ALTER FUNCTION asg.insert_asg(text, text, text, text, text, text, integer, integer, integer, integer, text, text, text[], text, text[], text[], text, text[], text, boolean, boolean, text[])
    OWNER TO postgres;
```

Python code looks like this

```
def insert_asg():
    #INSERT db from input json file to posgre sql table
    json_inputs = read_input_json(request.get_json())
    print(json_inputs)

    try:
        conn = connect()
        cur = conn.cursor()

        inserted_rows = 0
        query = "select asg.insert_list_asg("
        for json_input in json_inputs:    
            inserted_rows += 1
            for param in json_input:            #For Loop for transfering string that was read from json file, to string that can be applied to postgre function
                if type(param) is list:
                    param = (str(param)).replace("'", "")
                    param = (str(param)[1:-2]).replace("{", "[").replace("}","]")
                    param = "{" + param + "}"

                if type(param) is not str:
                    param = str(param)
                else:
                    param = "'" + param + "'"

                if param == "None":
                    param = "null"
                
                query = query + param + ", "

            commas = query.rfind(",") #This will return the index of the last comma, and in the next line we will remove it as that is last paramater we sent to postgres function
            query = query[:commas]
        query += ")"

        print(query)   
        # cur.execute(query)
        # conn.commit()   
        
        cur.close()
        return json.dumps({'success':True, 'inserted_rows':inserted_rows}), 200, {'ContentType':'application/json'}
```

I actually dont need help with python code, only with postgresql, but i added it there just if anyone need to take a look on it.

**Version of postgresql is 12.4 and version of python is 3.7**

Comment: Your code can be used for SQL injection. Are you sure you want this? And how does your json object look like? You could put it into your database function and let PostgreSQL handle it for you

Comment: Don't worry about sql injection. You sayin i can send a raw json with multiple objects inside(one object == one row) and postgresql can handle it? This is how it looks like: https://pastebin.com/WuY8YRQx

Comment: That's not a valid json object. But yes, you can do it in SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Small example with valid json:

```
WITH i(j) AS (
    SELECT
        '{
        "recommendation_account": "foo",
        "recommendation_region": "None",
        "recommendation_time": "13:39:00",
        "recommendations": ["bar","baz"]
        }'::json
), step_1 AS (
    INSERT INTO asg.asg (
        recommendation_account,
        recommendation_region,
        recommendation_time)        
    SELECT  NULLIF(j #>> '{recommendation_account}', 'None')
            , NULLIF(j #>> '{recommendation_region}', 'None')
            , (NULLIF(j #>> '{recommendation_time}', 'None'))::time -- Will fail when not valid
    FROM    i
    RETURNING asg.asg_id
)
INSERT INTO asg.recommendations(asg_id, recommendations_content)
SELECT  asg_id,
        recommendations_content
FROM    step_1
    ,   i
    ,   json_array_elements_text(j #> '{recommendations}') jae(recommendations_content)
RETURNING id;
```

But you have to be sure that you have a valid json object and all content also matches the datatypes in your tables.